# ¿Cómo solicitar contraseña en aplicación Java instalable?

Tags: java, validación, contraseña, inno-setup

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación Java la cual quiero que sea instalable, sin embargo, me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de que al momento de la instalación se solicite crear una contraseña para el usuario, con la cual solo él tendrá acceso a la aplicación.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Qué herramienta estás utilizando para hacer la aplicación instalable?

Comment: Inno Setup Compiler, pero en lo que visto e investigado no aclara como hacerlo. Muchas gracias por respoder y por la bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Quieres que la contraseña se pida para instalar la aplicación o que la aplicación de allí en adelante pida la contraseña para entrar?